# Relationship between measure theory and real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, big-picture

Does measure theory generalize real analysis to abstract spaces? For example, you can now talk about convergence even on unordered fields.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this...what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't received any answers, so here's my take after some additional reflection: the answer is yes - partly. Some aspects are generalized, mostly those dealing with integration over spaces, as tangentially/indirectly discussed in the preface of [Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by Folland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160).

Comment: ''The name "real analysis" is something of an anachronism. Originally applied to the theory of functions of a real variable, it has come to encompass several subjects of a more general and abstract nature that underlie much of modern analysis.''-Folland Where does it say that measure theory generalizes real analysis?!?! Folland writes no such nonsense.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker "...a more general and abstract nature that underlie much of modern analysis" and the extensive coverage of measure theory at the beginning show that "modern real analysis" has incorporated measure theory to study more than just "functions of a real variable".

Comment: Well, measure theory generalizes parts of real analysis. It certainly does not generalize the material on point set topology and functional anlysis in Folland's book.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I agree. My post and answer were probably a little too....general ;-) I guess it allows the key tools of convergence and integration to apply to a broader class of objects, but there are other areas where its not relevant. Ill qualify my post.